# How can I pass validationErrors from controller to a view?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

Well I have set `validationErrors` for login in my `UsersController`:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->User->validates() && $this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->set('ui', $this->Auth->user('id'));
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Loged in!'), 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $errors = $this->User->validationErrors;
        }
    }

}
```

Now how can I use `$error` in my view or as an element to be listed above my form?

Plz help I have searched a lot, but the answers were for old CakePHP, and I am using CakePHP 2.3.8.

Answer (score 1):

### Validation errors are available in the view automatically

There is no action required to get validation errors in the view, as they are [a property of the view class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L947). They can be inspected simply with:

```
debug($this->validationErrors);
```

In the view.

### But you probably don't need to access them

Note however that it's not normal to need to look at this property directly. Using the form helper errors are displayed automatically, or you can [generate errors individually](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::error)

```
if ($this->Form->isFieldError('email')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('email');
}
```

Comment: You see I want to make something like [this tutorial](http://milesj.me/blog/read/cakephp-list-errors) in CakePHP 2.3 and I am not using it for login form it's a product form. Can you help me with that? or can you at least be more specific about how I can use this `isFieldError` to show all the validation errors as a list -say above the form- in the view. I do apologize if the question sounds stupid.

Comment: If you want to follow the linked tutorial - just replace `$errors` with `$this->validationErrors`. Note that this is a 2 dimensional array however.

Comment: Btw - the code in the tutorial will "just work" - irrespective of the version of cake you are using.